# How to changing menu item text?

Tags: java, android

When a user hit the "register" menu item it come to the register activity and after hit the button to return to the `MainActivity` with the menu item from "register" to "unregister" I don't know how would I go about changing the menu item text.

```
public class register extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
        Button register = findViewById(R.id.reg);
        EditText name =findViewById(R.id.name);
        EditText admin = findViewById(R.id.admin);
        EditText email = findViewById(R.id.email);

        register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(register.this,MainActivity.class));   
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `onPrepareOptionsMenu`:

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuItem btn = menu.findItem(R.id.register_menu_item);
    if (/* here check if user is registered or not */) {
        btn.setTitle("Unregister");
    } else {
        btn.setTitle("Register");
    }
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```